# Proving $m(B)=\sum_{n\in B}\frac{1}{2^n}$ is a measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $A=\{1, 2, ...\}$ and let $m: \mathcal{P}(A)\to[0,\infty]\quad m(B)=\begin{cases}\sum_{n\in B} \frac{1}{2^n},\;|B|<\infty\\\infty,\;|B|=\infty \end{cases}$.

I am trying to prove that $m$ is a measure.

I am not able to prove the countable additivity property.

I start by assuming $B_1,B_2,\ldots\in\mathcal P(A)$ are disjoint.

If at least one of $B_i$ is infinite then their union is also infinite and the property holds.

If all $B_i$ are finite then does it hold that $\sum_{n\in\cup_iB_i}\frac1{2^n} = \sum_i\left(\sum_{n\in B_i}\frac1{2^n}\right)$ and if it does is it enough to complete the proof?

Edit: If it actually isn't countably additive, is it still finitely additive?

Comment: It's not countably additive.

Comment: Okay... Is there a simple counterexample?

Comment: If you write B as union of singletons, than this should add up to 1. While $m(B)=\infty$

Answer (score 4):

We have $m(\mathbb{N})=\infty$ since $|\mathbb{N}|=\infty$.

But $\mathbb{N}=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{n\}$ leads to:

$m(\mathbb{N})=m(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{n\})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty m(\{n\})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}=1$. Which is a contradiction.